# Usos del subjuntivo para expresar 'grados de posibilidad': el presente vs el imperfecto

Tags: subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

Normalmente, a mi entender, la decisión de utilizar o el presente del subjuntivo o el imperfecto está vinculada al "tiempo" del verbo en la cláusula principal:

> Quiero que me ayudes

> Quería que me ayudaras

Bien, pero sé que también la decisión de usar o el presente del subjuntivo o el imperfecto depende de si pensamos que la cosa es probable o no. Por ejemplo

> Parece que viva / viviera agobiado por problemas únicos e irresolubles

Mi pregunta es ¿cuándo está permitido elegir entre el presente del subjuntivo y el imperfecto del subjuntivo para expresar 'grados de creencia' en un sujeto? Sinceramente, no sé cuáles son los lugares donde se puede elegir, y cuáles son los limites de este uso. Por ejemplo, en las siguientes frases

> 1. Buscamos a alguien que sepa nadar
> 2. Buscábamos a alguien que supiera nadar
> 3. ?? Buscamos a alguien que supiera nadar

¿Es posible usar el imperfecto del subjuntivo en frase 3 solo para expresar más 'duda' sobre si esa persona que buscamos existe?

En resumen, ¿cuáles son las situaciones en las que se puede elegir el uno o el otro?

Comment: Parece que vivE / viviera agobiado por problemas únicos e irresolubles

Comment: @cocteau Yo creo que en el caso del ejemplo sí es aceptable la forma "viva". Es decir, que la frase "Parece que viva agobiado por problemas únicos e irresolubles" me parece correcta.

Comment: @karloswitt "viva" es subjuntivo presente de 1ra y 3ra persona ¿Por qué lo usarías en una afirmación? En mi forma de verlo o como lo conozco es en frases interrogativas como: ¿De verdad te parece que viva/vive agobiado? o negativas: "No me parece que viva/No me pareció(indicativo pretérito simple) que viviera agobiado". Si quisiera decir "Parece/pareciera/es como si..." estaría forzado a usar ""vive"(indicativo presente) en el caso de "parece y pareciera" o "viviera"(subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto) por concordancia con pareciera(sólo en ese caso) o usando "es como si".

Answer (score 1):

En:

> Quiero que me **ayudes**(subjuntivo presente)<-Sí, AHORA

"Quiero que me **ayudas**" NO.

> Quería que me **ayudaras**(subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto)<-Sí, Pasado, no especifica cuando, alguna gente dice que expresa cortesía.

"Quería que me **ayudabas**" NO.

---

En:

> Parece que viva / viviera agobiado por problemas únicos e irresolubles

- Parece que **vive**[indicativo **presente**] agobiado por problemas únicos e irresolubles.<-Sí, suposición en presente.
- Parece que **viva**[subjuntivo **presente**] agobiado por problemas únicos e irresolubles.<-NO, me suena extraño. ¿De verdad te parece que (él o yo) viva agobiado...?<-Sí, como pregunta.
- Parece que **vivía**[indicativo **pretérito imperfecto**] agobiado por problemas únicos e irresolubles.<-Sí, "Al parecer vivía", "Supuestamente vivía" es una suposición actual del pasado.
- Parece que **viviera**[subjuntivo **pretérito imperfecto** ]  agobiado por problemas únicos e irresolubles.<-Sí, Duda, también se usa como presente, "Es como si (yo-1ra pers) viviera"/"Es como si (él-3ra pers) viviera". "Si eso sucede, entonces es como si ..."(concreto->irreal)

---

En:

> Buscamos a alguien que sepa nadar/Buscabamos a alguien que supiera nadar/??? Buscamos a alguien que supiera nadar

- **Buscamos**[indicativo **presente**] (a) alguien que **sepa**[subjuntivo presente] nadar (ahora mismo lo están buscando)
- **Buscamos**[indicativo **pretérito perfecto simple**] (a) alguien que **supiera**[subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto] nadar(Lo buscaron y tienen la certeza de si lo encontraron o no/de (no) haberlo encontrado)
- **Buscábamos**[indicativo **pretérito imperfecto**] (a) alguien que **supiera**[subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto] nadar(Lo buscaron reiteradas veces || Lo buscaron y no está claro de si lo encontraron o no en ese entonces || Cuando lo buscaron simultaneamente ocurrío otro evento, p.ej: Mientras estábamos construyendo la piscina)

Me suena mal:

- Buscamos (a) alguien que **sabe**[indicativo presente] nadar'. <-NO, pero probablemente se dice en alguna región.
- Buscamos/Buscábamos (a) alguien que **sabía**[indicativo pretérito imperfecto] nadar'. <-NO, pero probablemente se dice en alguna región.

Incluso me suena bien 'hubiera/hubiese sabido' en Y.

---

EDIT:

Hoy escuché algo parecido a esto y es imposible tener la certeza de sus habilidades, no estamos seguros hasta que vemos como se desempeña.La manera de introducir el indicativo en el ejemplo en mi variedad sería:

> 1a) Buscábamos a alguien que **supiera**(subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto) nadar y encontramos a A que (sí) **sabía**(indicativo pretérito imperfecto) porque el tiene años de experiencia como salvavidas.

> 1b) Buscábamos a alguien que **supiera**(subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto) nadar porque A se fue de vacaciones y B que no **sabía**(indicativo pretérito imperfecto)(sí) **supo**/**pudo**(indicativo pretérito perfecto simple) arreglárselas con lo que aprendió/había aprendido de A.

Al decir "supo" dejamos claro que es un conocimiento nuevo que adquirió cubriendo una necesidad y con "sabía" algo que se tiene.

> 2a) **Encontramos** a alguien que (sí) **sabía**(indicativo pretérito imperfecto) nadar y eso nos alivió un montón.

o

> 2b) Al final (sí) **pudimos encontrar** a alguien que **supiera**(subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto) nadar y eso nos alivió un montón.

En 2b) no indica incertidumbre porque de hecho sí lo encontraron, tal vez el hablante no recuerda con claridad en ese momento lo que ocurrió en ese entonces o no le interesa entrar en detalles.

En el caso que otra gente lo hubiera recomendado 3a) aún así sería algo como:

> 3a) "Buscábamos a alguien que **supiera**(subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto) nadar y ellos recomendaron a alguien que (sí) **sabía**"(indicativo pretérito imperfecto)

Sí decimos:

> 4a) "Buscábamos a alguien que **sabía** de armas"

Al decir "sabía" dejamos claro que si la encontramos sí o sí nos va a ayudar, pero no nos interesa su expertise para tener un respaldo, lo decimos porque tenemos la creencia fundada o infundada de que él sabe algo que nos podría llegar a servir, el fin es identificarlo, p.ej para encontrar una pista de quién las robó o usamos ese tiempo porque ocurre simultáneamente a otro evento.

En cambio, si decimos:

> 4b)"Buscábamos a alguien que **supiera** de armas"

Al decir "supiera" no está claro de si lo encontraron o no, pero sí recalcamos que nos interesaba su expertise para contratarlo o para proveernos de algo.

A su vez, si decimos:

> 4c)"Buscábamos a alguien que **supiera** de armas"

También puede llegar a significar lo mismo que 4a) (porque **sabía**(indicativo pretérito imperfecto) en la subordinada me sigue sonando fuera de lugar) pero en ese caso, al usar "supiera", no estamos poniendo en duda lo que "sabía", porque en realidad perseguimos una pista no a un experto.

Es como si dijéramos:

> 4d) "Buscábamos a alguien **experto** en armas"

Y, al decir eso, se cubriría el caso 4c) sin el peligro de ambigüedades, el caso 4b) y el caso 4a) pero sin explícitar la finalidad o la intención de su búsqueda.

Comment: "Buscamos a alguien que sabe nadar" (con *a* personal) es correcto: quiere decir "Buscamos a cierta persona [específica, aunque no nombrada] que [sabemos que] sabe nadar". Sin la *a* personal se vuelve incorrecto, porque la *a* marca al objeto directo personal como específico, y esto es requisito para usar el indicativo en este caso.

Comment: La RAE dice que con el v. buscar la prep. 'a' puede aparecer o no, creo q si es más necesaria en el indic. que en el subj., pero uno u otro no me indican esa dif. entre partic. o espec. como sí podría hacerlo la prep. En la práctica simplemente se usa el subj y por usarlo no se crea una duda ante la existencia o no de ese alguien, ni se constata un hecho con el indicat. tampoco porque simple% no es usado por un determinado grupo éste último. P.ej en buscamos a alg que tiene armas(incautación)/buscamos (a) alguien que tenga armas(proveerse de), incluso ahí pueden llegar a ser intercambiables.

Answer (score 1):

En oraciones afirmativas como éstas, donde hay una cláusula principal y una subordinada, encontramos un verbo principal en indicativo (VI) y un verbo subordinado en subjuntivo (VS); los tiempos de VI y VS se correlacionan de manera similar a las correlaciones que existen en inglés. (En inglés se nombran tradicionalmente como *first, second, third conditional* a estas formas.)

En la cláusula subordinada, normalmente, la alternancia posible es de modo: subjuntivo o indicativo; los tiempos posibles están determinados por el tiempo del verbo principal. La alternancia es posible con ciertos verbos, no con todos.

Correlación de tiempos:

1. Quiero que me ayudes.
2. Quería que me ayudaras.
3. (Habría querido que me hubieras ayudado.) [esta es muy extraña]

Alternancia de modos:

1. Parece que vive agobiado.
2. Parece que viviera agobiado.

En cada caso hay que saber qué verbos toleran alternar modos y cuáles no. Por ejemplo, *creer* no lo permite:

1. Creo que vive agobiado.
2. *Creo que viviera agobiado. [incorrecto]

En negaciones, preguntas y algunos otros contextos hipotéticos, hay verbos como *creer* y *parecer* que cambian indicativo por subjuntivo en la subordinada:

1. No parece que viva agobiado.
2. No parecía que viviera agobiado.
3. ¿Parece que viva agobiado?
4. Parece (im)posible/(im)probable que viva agobiado.

En los otros ejemplos aparece el asunto de la *a* personal, que es una marca de objeto directo para seres animados específicos. Generalmente, si se usa la *a* personal, al tratarse de un objeto específico, el verbo puede ir en indicativo o en subjuntivo; si no se usa, el objeto pasa a ser inespecífico/hipotético y el verbo debe ir en subjuntivo:

1. Buscamos a alguien que sabe nadar. [una persona específica y particular]
2. Buscamos a alguien que sepa nadar. [una persona que sepa nadar]
3. Buscamos alguien que sepa nadar. [cualquier persona que sepa nadar]

En la práctica las opciones 2 y 3 significan lo mismo y el contraste mayor se da entre 1 y 2–3, pero en la opción 2, el hablante puede transmitir la impresión de tener más claro qué busca. Pasando esto a tiempo pasado, quedaría:

1. Buscábamos a alguien que sabía nadar.
2. Buscábamos a alguien que supiera nadar.
3. Buscábamos alguien que supiera nadar.

(Usé el imperfecto y no el pretérito perfecto porque es idéntico al presente en esta persona y número, pero también podría haber funcionado.)

Comment: gracias, es lo que buscaba, pero en tu segunda lista, cuando pasa al imperfecto, ¿es una elección libre, es decir, para añadir un matiz de incertidumbre?  Si es así, ¿en qué casos se puede hacerlo, es decir, cambiar el presente del subjuntivo al imperfecto para añadir 'aún más incertidumbre', si puedo expresarlo así?

Comment: En “Parece que vive/viviera agobiado” el cambio que importa es el de modo (de indicativo a subjuntivo), y el cambio de tiempo no indica nada, es automático. No puede decirse “Parece que \*viva agobiado” (presente del subjuntivo), es agramatical.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una correlación entre tiempos.

- *Busco* a alguien que *sepa* nadar (presente indicativo + presente subjuntivo)
- *Buscaba* a alguien que *supiera* nadar (pretérito imperfecto indicativo + pretérito imperfecto subjuntivo)
- *Busqué* a alguien que *supiera* nadar (pretérito perfecto simple indicativo + pretérito imperfecto subjuntivo)

Esto no se puede decir: "*Busco* a alguien que *supiera* nadar", da igual el grado de creencia.

Hay otras correlaciones para otros tiempos, por ejemplo:

- *Buscaría* a alguien si *supiera* que hace falta (condicional + pretérito imperfecto subjuntivo)
- *Buscaría* a alguien que *supiera* nadar, si tú me lo pidieras (condicional + pretérito imperfecto subjuntivo)

Comment: "Buscamos" es "indicativo pretérito perfecto simple" e "indicativo presente", "Nosotros buscamos a alguien que sepa (ahora)" y "Nosotros (sí) buscamos a alguien que supiera (en ese entonces)" Si decimos "Buscábamos"(indicativo pretérito imperfecto) en mi variedad significa que cuando lo hacíamos se desarrollaba otra acción.

Comment: Ej. En ese entonces, buscamos(indicativo pretérito perfecto simple) a alguien que tuviera(subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto) una verdadera conexión con el caso.

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta para usar singular y evitar confusiones. Siempre me estaba refiriendo al presente de indicativo, ya que la pregunta era si el tiempo del subjuntivo dependía del grado de creencia.

Comment: El ejemplo del OP fue con "Buscamos/Buscábamos" primera persona del plural, no con la primera persona del singular de tus ejemplos, eso precisamente aumenta más la confusión. Además dices que da igual el grado de creencia y no das ninguna argumentación.